# How can I make raster effects permanent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, effects

I'm creating a logo where I have applied a stamp effect to the text and boundary.

How can I make the stamp effect become permanent without needing to have the 'art' underneath masked by the opacity mask?

Is it even necessary? I'm concerned that people opening the file in the future could easily change the logo, accidentally or on purpose.

[image: logo screenshot]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the stamp effect is a raster effect, not a vector one. I would avoid using those for logo creation; or if it's really necessary then just make sure the final output is 100% vector.

Comment: you typically give your clients flattened files so that 'accidental changes' can't happen. If it's a raster effect, then you likely need to export flat raster images (JPGs, TIFFs, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, you can use `Object > Flatten Transparency` however that simply will yield *more* raster objects in many cases.

A great deal depends upon what the **basis** of the **Opacity Mask** is.

- If the Opacity Mask is created using vector content then the Flatten Transparency command will work.
- If the Opacity Mask is created using a raster image you've got a couple hurdles to overcome.

  1. How do you expect a logo to scale if it uses raster-based content? It won't scale well regardless of what you do.
  2. To overcome the limitations of raster content, use **Live Trace** (CS5-) or **Image Trace** (AICS6+) to trace the raster texture so it is vector, then apply the Opacity mask. Or better yet, simply use the **Pathfinder Panel** or the **Shape Builder Tool** to combine the texture with the other artwork. No need for a mask at all. Of course, doing this may mean you lose some subtle transitions in the texture. But honestly, those subtle transitions would never hold up under scaling and printing of a logo anyway - they'll only look decent on screen where sizes are small and everything is a pixel anyway.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy all layers, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> paste into a new layer. This will create a new layer that is the combined effect of all layers as they currently appear onscreen.

If you don't want to keep the editable layers, you could just select the layers in the layers panel, right-click and flatten.

Comment: er.... this sounds like Photoshop, not Illustrator.

Comment: So it does... Whoops - Didn't see the illustrator tag. Anyway, if someone wants to know how to do it in Photoshop, maybe this will save a question in the future...